anything wrong with this invention disclaimer paragraph?
Examples of additional features and/or benefits have been described as potential consequences or side effects of some embodiments of the present disclosure. For instance, implementing an embodiment of the present disclosure may enable a platform to additionally extend feature X and/or enhance feature Y. However, it should be understood that the invention does not depend on these additional features, which are optional.

Feature X and feature Y are both argued to be useful features. Implementing some embodiments of the invention is argued to help enable or facilitate feature X and feature Y.
Therefore, this is another use case of the invention. This use case may also help with the non-obviousness of the invention.
Feature X and feature Y are not novel, and it is not part of the invention.
So the purpose of the disclaimer is to further clarify this point.
Questions:

Is there a term for this type of language or paragraph, such as "invention disclaimer", etc.?
Is this type of language commonly used?
What are the pros and cons?
Should I remove it or keep it?


Could you please try breaking it down from one long sentence to several sentences. It’s hard to process as it is.

@EricS thanks for the advise, I reduced it to three sentences. please review.

Much better, thanks.

I see no reason to disclaim anything.
I do not think there is any reason to list things that are not being claimed. The specification is to explain your invention and not to say what it isn’t.
The exception is laying the foundation for negative claiming.
“Invention” is also a dirty word. If used it needs to equal exactly what is claimed. You often see “the invention, as claimed,”
If the optional features are not part of the invention I assume they are not claimed in dependent claims? Anything in any claim is part of “the invention”.

In each of the three instances of the spec where the word "invention" is used, it is for "disclaimers". For example, "the invention does not...".

I edited my answer to add more details

And yes, the feature X and feature Y are not part any claims, dependent or independent.
